# Jump to last frame of video and pause

Tags: javascript

How do you make a function that goes to the last frame of the video and then pauses? I thought I'd be able to get the duration of the video and then set the time to that and pause/play, but that seems to not work at all.

```
function goToLast() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("videoID");
  var videoTime = vid.duration;
  vid.currentTime = videoTime;
  vid.pause()
}
```

Comment: You don’t really have access on a frame level, only time-based - and even that only with [reduced precision](Reduced_time_precision). I am not sure if you can get this to work automatically; think you might have to figure out the correct time value through a bit of trial & error on the level of the individual video, and then use this as a magic number inside your script. The other option would perhaps be that you get the last frame extracted as a static image, and then use that as placeholder for the not yet playing video.

Answer (score 1):

From working with videos before I came to the conclusion that frames are not a thing in videos players in JS.

So what you need to do is find what the FPS of the video is (that may not be provided to you unfortunately so you can assume that it's 60 or 30 FPS ) and calculate the time duration that will take you to the next frame.

e.g 1 sec / 60fps = 0.016667 seconds

This is the time interval of a frame.

Then subtract the frame duration from the total duration and you have arrived at the last frame.

So if you total duration is 120 secs then the last frame is 120 - 0.016667